# What happens during string initialization?

Tags: c#

What happens exactly during string initialization?

```
string s = "Hello World!";
```

Is it going to make a call to any of these constructors?

```
public String(char* value);
public String(char[] value);
```

Comment: `s` will be assigned the reference of the *interned* string `"Hello World!"`. The string object is constructed by the runtime, so asking for the exact details makes this a good question. The definitive answer lies somewhere in [CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took a look at the CoreCLR repository to see what `ldstr` (see Filip Bulovic's answer) does under the hood and found the path to be something like this:

1. `[vm/interpreter.cpp]` The interpreter's IL evaluation loop hits [`case CEE_LDSTR`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/vm/interpreter.cpp#L2795) and calls [`Interpreter::LdStr()`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/vm/interpreter.cpp#L5828)
2. `LdStr()` calls [`ConstructStringLiteral`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/vm/jithelpers.cpp#L2972) and passes the module of the current method and the string pointer (current IL instruction location + 1)
3. `[vm/jithelpers.cpp]` `ConstructStringLiteral` calls [`Module::ResolveStringRef`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/vm/ceeload.cpp#L5044)
4. `[vm/ceeload.cpp]` `ResolveStringRef` calls [`InitializeStringData`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/vm/ceeload.cpp#L4931), then [`LoaderAllocator::GetStringObjRefPtrFromUnicodeString`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/vm/loaderallocator.cpp#L1469)
5. `[vm/loaderallocator.cpp]` `GetStringObjRefPtrFromUnicodeString` calls the LoaderAllocator specific string literal map's [`GetStringLiteral`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/vm/stringliteralmap.cpp#L148)
6. `[vm/stringliteralmap.cpp]` `GetStringLiteral` hashes the string and attempts to get the string object from the local string entry hash table. If found, the string object from the hash table is returned. If not, then an attempt is made to [get the string object from the global string literal map](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/vm/stringliteralmap.cpp#L377). If the literal isn't found from the global map, it's added to the global map with [`GlobalStringLiteralMap::AddStringLiteral`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/vm/stringliteralmap.cpp#L498).
7. `AddStringLiteral` creates the COM+ string object with a call to [`AllocateStringObject`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/vm/stringliteralmap.cpp#L459), allocates an object handle for it, and adds the literal to the table as the key and the object as the value.

   - `AllocateStringObject`: the char count is counted, a [call is made to the garbage collector](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/vm/gchelpers.cpp#L773) to allocate a string of that size, the string constant is copied to the COM+ string object, the string object is tested with [`GetIsOnlyLowChars`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/vm/eehash.h#L441), if true, the flag `STRING_STATE_FAST_OPS` is set in the COM+ string object "*[...which indicates if the string can be sorted in a fast way](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/vm/stringliteralmap.cpp#L486). The flag is persisted to assembly containing the string literals. We restore the flag when we load strings from assembly...*"

     - `GetIsOnlyLowChars` does a bitwise AND with `ONLY_LOW_CHARS_MASK` (which is `0x80000000`) and the characters in the string and returns true if the string contains only characters less than 0x80. The managed (internal) methods `String.IsFastSort()`<sup>[ref](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,5092bca0e64fd4ba)|[src](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/classlibnative/bcltype/stringnative.cpp#L212)</sup> and `String.IsAscii()`<sup>[ref](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,0c1a6eb865dfa7dd)|[src](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/classlibnative/bcltype/stringnative.cpp#L235)</sup> make use of this.
8. All the way back in [vm/interpreter.cpp]: The string object handle get pushed to the stack.

In conclusion, string literals take quite a specific path which doesn't make any calls to the managed `String(char *)` or `String(char[])` constructor. However, I haven't found the implementation for those constructors yet so I can only assume that they both make a call to `AllocateStringObject` at some point.

I hope this answer fits your idea of "exactly".

Answer (score 2):

Here is C#:

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    string hello = "Hello World!";
    Console.WriteLine (hello);
}
```

and here is IL:

```
// method line 2
.method public static hidebysig 
       default void Main (string[] args)  cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x20f4
.entrypoint
// Code size 13 (0xd)
.maxstack 2
.locals init (
    string  V_0)
IL_0000:  ldstr "Hello World!"
IL_0005:  stloc.0 
IL_0006:  ldloc.0 
IL_0007:  call void class [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_000c:  ret 
} // end of method MainClass::Main
```

> The ldstr instruction pushes an object reference (type O) to a new
>   string object representing the specific string literal stored in the
>   metadata. The ldstr instruction allocates the requisite amount of
>   memory and performs any format conversion required to convert the
>   string literal from the form used in the file to the string format
>   required at runtime.